# Best practice for passing object between user controls on a wizard (tab control)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a wizard using the winforms tab control (hiding the tabs and using "previous" and "next" buttons).  Each page of the wizard is a separate user control, but they all update a common object.  I need the ability to move forward or backward and persist the data at each step, even skipping steps if they are optional.

I'm tempted to create a "global" object for the wizard that all user controls can access, but I'm certain that is not a best practice.  What is the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: Pass them all a reference to the same object?

Comment: Data-binding will probably be very useful to you here. With data-binding, a change in the property of an object will automatically be reflected in the control it's bound to. That way, if you have the same information on multiple tabs, changing it in one place will update it everywhere else.

Comment: One has to be careful when using data-binding with Tab controls as the data will not be pushed to the controls on a tab page until said page is at least shown once. Not saying it's impossible, just saying one has to know about this little quirck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your modified Tab control resides on a form, simply make the "data" object as a member of the form class.

That way you'll have access to it from anywhere within the form, thus you can pass a reference to it to the custom UserControls whenever you navigate the wizard.

Cheers

Comment: Would you pass the reference to the constructor of the user control?  Or pass it each time the wizard hits that page?

Comment: In the constructor would be good. Since you're passing a reference, even if there are changes done to the object in between calls to different pages, you will always have the current object state